# Ajax and Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-geocoder

I am trying to get user's city using geokit and Google Geocoder. I am getting the user's city from an ajax request:

```
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize(position) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var long = position.coords.longitude;

    getCitizenCity(lat, long);
}

function getCitizenCity(lat, long) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/set_citizen_city",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { lat: lat, long: long },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        } 
    });
}

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', getLocation);
```

The rails code (HomeController.rb):

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

   attr_reader :citizen_city

   def index
   end

   def set_citizen_city
      lat = params[:lat]
      long = params[:long]

      address = Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.reverse_geocode("#{lat}, #{long}")
      @citizen_city = address.city

      respond_to do |format|
          format.json { render :json => {:message => "Success"} }
      end
   end
end
```

I have noticed that if I do

```
    puts @citizen_city
```

inside the method "set_citizen_city", the correct city is shown in the console.
But, if I try

```
puts @citizen_city
```

inside the method "index", nothing is displayed in the console.

What do I have to do to display the city's name on the console?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't see`@citizen_city` in index is because it is not defined there.

On every request Rails does a new instance of the application(as far as I know) so controller instance variables can't be accessed if they are not defined in the same action. To fix this I suggest you save the `lat` and `long` params in the database and then in index just do the same thing you do in `set_citizen_city` when defining `@citizen_city` only then look up coordinates from the database(or possibly session params, if that's what you need)